# Angular 2: routing within a module (secondary nested router-outlet)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've been playing around with the Angular 2 webpack starter found [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter), which has a ton of useful examples. I've run into an issue with routing, though. I've removed a few of the modules & added one of my own, which contains children (I'm still not sure if using child modules or child components would be best practice- I'm currently trying this with components).

My objective is to be able to switch between top-level modules as normal (`Home` and `About`, in this case), but after loading my `Home` module, swap between multiple child components (or modules, if that's better supported) within the `Home` module's template.

I'm trying to use another `<router-outlet>` within `Home`- I've tried naming it & using the `outlet` paramter in the `Home` module routing definition, but clicking links to load within `Home` doesn't currently work. Code below:

This is my current app structure (with most of the extra webpack stuff left out):

```
app
  |-app.component.ts (template contains router-outlet)
  |-app.module.ts
  |-app.routes.ts
  |-about
    |-about.component.ts
    |-about.component.html
  |-home
    |-home.module.ts
    |-home.component.ts
    |-home.component.html (contains router outlet for children)
    |-home.routes.ts
    |-signup
      |-signup.component.ts
      |-signup.component.html
    |-login
      |-login.component.ts
      |-login.component.html
```

This is my app.component, which is almost the same as it starts in the starter repo- I just added a link to my own module & removed the others:

**app.component.ts**

```
import {
 Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: [
    './app.component.css'
  ],
  template: `
    <nav>
      <a [routerLink]=" ['./home'] " routerLinkActive="active">
        Home
      </a>      
      <a [routerLink]=" ['./about'] " routerLinkActive="active">
        About
      </a>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public appState: AppState
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Initial App State', this.appState.state);
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {
  NgModule,
  ApplicationRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  removeNgStyles,
  createNewHosts,
  createInputTransfer
} from '@angularclass/hmr';
import {
  RouterModule,
  PreloadAllModules
} from '@angular/router';

/*
 * Platform and Environment providers/directives/pipes
 */
import { ENV_PROVIDERS } from './environment';
import { ROUTES } from './app.routes';
// App is our top level component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_RESOLVER_PROVIDERS } from './app.resolver';
import { AppState, InternalStateType } from './app.service';
import { AboutComponent } from './about';
import { HomeModule } from './home';
import { XLargeDirective } from './home/x-large';

// app services needed globally
import { AuthenticationService, UserService, AlertService } from './shared';

import '../styles/styles.scss';
import '../styles/headings.css';

// Application wide providers
const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  ...APP_RESOLVER_PROVIDERS,
  AppState
];

type StoreType = {
  state: InternalStateType,
  restoreInputValues: () => void,
  disposeOldHosts: () => void
};

/**
 * `AppModule` is the main entry point into Angular2's bootstraping process
 */
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    NoContentComponent,
    XLargeDirective
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
    ENV_PROVIDERS,
    APP_PROVIDERS,
    UserService,
    AuthenticationService,
    AlertService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(
    public appRef: ApplicationRef,
    public appState: AppState
  ) {}

}
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeModule } from './home';
import { AboutComponent } from './about';

import { DataResolver } from './app.resolver';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home#HomeModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Navigation to my Home module works fine- I think the issue is the routing within it. This is the Home module, component, & routing.

**home.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './home.routes';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

console.log('`Home` loaded');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Components / Directives/ Pipes
    HomeComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
})
export class HomeModule {
  public static routes = routes;
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements {

}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<div>
    <h2>Hello from home module</h2>
</div>
<span>
    <a [routerLink]=" ['./signup'] ">
    Sign Up
    </a>
</span>
<span>
    <a [routerLink]=" ['./login'] ">
    Login
    </a>
</span>
<router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
<div>
    <h2>Bottom info</h2>
</div>
```

**home.routes.ts**

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

export const routes = [
    {   path: '', 
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'signup',
                component: SignupComponent,
                outlet: 'aux'
            },
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent,
                outlet: 'aux'
            }
        ] }
];
```

The current behavior is that nothing happens when I click one of the links for `Signup` or `Login` - no errors, but the components are not loaded at the `aux` router-outlet, either.

I've tried configuring `Signup` as a module, but that hasn't worked for me yet either- I think there's some extra config that I don't understand, and figured treating the children as components would help me understand the basic required routing.

From researching this question, it seems like multiple router-outlets hasn't been well supported, especially using them with the `router-link` syntax, until around RC5. [This recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42204114/2738238) to a similar question suggests that it does work now, but similar syntax isn't working for me.

Is it an issue to have the `router-outlets` nested? Should I be defining the `Signup` and `Login` components as modules instead? Or is there some other problem altogether with the way I've defined the routing, perhaps at the uppermost AppModule level?

**EDIT**

I've added `app.module.ts` to the question. Additionally, after looking at the base configuration of the starter project I used, it seems like using child modules can simplify things- specifically the `barrel` module (viewable [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/tree/master/src/app/%2Bbarrel)) has a `child-barrel` module, and it's loaded into the `router-outlet` present in the `barrel.component` template. If there was a `child-barrel-2` module at the same level, this would be the sort of thing I'm looking for.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112891/angular-2-rc5-router-outlet-inside-another-router-outlet), where the top answer states that

> Modules are recommended

Should I be trying to mimic the structure of the starter, where the parent-child relationship is accomplished by using modules?

Comment: Did you import your home.module into your app.module? And make sure it will be imported before your root router. Otherwise your ** route will always be matched before any route of your home routes and you will alway be redirected to your home component. Also check the documentation for routing https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: aux outlets require ugly urls like `<a [routerLink]="['/home', { outlets: {'route1':['page1'] }}]"></a>` and they might be not what you expect from them )

Comment: @pode I did import the `Home` module in app.module (just updated the question to add `app.module.ts`). My understanding is the import is all that's required since the module is lazy-loaded- is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using '.' in front of '/' in `<a [routerLink]=" ['./signup'] ">` Try removing it.
.what is your base href

**EDIT**

Why don't you try something like this in template.

`<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: 'home', aux: 'signup'}}]">signup </a>`

and below code in routes config

`{path: 'signup', component: signUpComponent, outlet:"aux"}`

Comment: I thought that might be the issue as well, but removing the './' didn't help- though I didn't get much chance to test that. I'll try it again when I have the opportunity.

Comment: I'll try that updated `routerLink` syntax as soon as I can- thanks!

Comment: I just tried both suggestions- removing './' didn't affect anything, and when I updated the `[routerLink]` syntax, I can see that change when I hover the link ( it has `http://localhost:3000/home/(home//aux:signup)` ) but no action when I click it.

Comment: Wait, no- I'm dumb. Your suggestion about removing the './' seems to have worked- I must have had something else wrong when I tried it this morning. I'll accept your answer!

Comment: thanks! this brought me to https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets, which is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Angular version is **Angular: 14.1.0**

You can something like this in routes config.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [{
      path: 'test1', component: Test1Component
    },
    {
      path: 'test2', component: Test2Component
    }]
  },
  { path: '**', component: WelcomeComponent }
];
```

And in your type script code, you should be doing this...

```
  gotolink() {
    console.log("In gototlink child navi");
    
    this.router.navigate(['test1'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
  }
```

In the above code this is important...
**{ relativeTo: this.activatedRoute }**

Comment: And if we would like to move to the other page via the routerLink tag, how could we proceed?