# Routes under Routes - Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes, ngroute

i have a dashboard component with a sub component called SMS. Now, the SMS component also has it routing list. How can i route under the sms navigation bar under the dashboard component. When i am routing under the sms bar, the navigation bar for the sms should not disappear. Below is the screenshot. 
In my code, when i click on the quicksms, it routes me to the quicksms page and the navigation bar disappears.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112891/angular-2-rc5-router-outlet-inside-another-router-outlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the sms routes. This should work fine!!

**dashboard routes**

```
export const DashboardRoutes: Routes =[

  {
    path: 'dashboard',

    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [

        {path:'messages', component: MessageComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]

  children:[
                {
                    path:'transactional', component:quickSmsComponent
                }



        ]


},


    ]

  }
];
```